ssh command strange behaviour in Linux
I am using ssh command to connect and execute a few commands on the remote server. It can be done both by directly providing the command I want to execute and through a file by redirecting the output to ssh command.
Now, I found this behaviour strange.
ssh -q user@server "cat"

this gets stuck as it is waiting for a filename.
ssh -q user@server < filename.txt

this executed and returns the command prompt instantly.
filename.txt has cat as its content.
Can someone please help me to understand the reason behind this behaviour?
Have gone through some links but it was not helpful

The first example is not waiting for a filename. cat without an argument reads from its standard input, which is the terminal in this case. So it's waiting for you to type the content that will be printed. Just as if you type cat into the local shell -- it will repeat back whatever you type until you type the EOF character (usually Ctl-d).
The second example runs an interactive shell on the remote system, with its standard input redirected to the SSH connection. ssh has its input redirected to the file. So the remote shell receives the command cat followed by EOF. It executes the cat command, which reads from its standard input; it immediately reads EOF, so it exits. Then the shell exits because it also reads EOF from the connection. So there's no output.
